# How does someone get 50 points in physics stack exchange before asking or answering a single question

Tags: discussion

I guess I don't understand the stack exchange well, does one automatically get points in a different stack exchange if they have points from other stack exchanges?

Comment: Out of the association bonus: there are possibility for that: 1) To have 25 approved edits. For an approved edit, you get +2. 2) You can also win a bounty. | Although none of them is very common between the rep1 accounts, the possibility exists.

Comment: @peterh I think you can't win a bounty without answering a question.  However I suppose it's possible to write an answer, win a bounty, and have your answer deleted.  Seems like  pink elephant hunting, though.

Comment: @rob Well, I agree in everything. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, If you have at least 200 rep on any of the SE sites you are registered to, you get a 100 rep bonus each time you register to new SE.

Every new user gets 1 rep for registration.

Blog post about this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/